# jQuery menu-hiding triggers at wrong window width in Firefox - what do I do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, cross-browser, responsive-design

I've built a website at http://www.fpsl.eu which has a normal horizontal navigation menu at large screen sizes, and a jQuery dropdown which hides the menu (#mmenu) until a button is clicked.

This dropdown is supposed to trigger at widths less than 980px, and it does so in Chrome, Safari and Internet Explorer.

However, in Firefox, #mmenu disappears at 994px leaving the navigation bar blank (the button is controlled by CSS media queries so at 994px it's still set to display:none). At 980px the mobile menu displays as expected.

What on earth do I do? I'm kind of freaking out since this basically spoils my attempts to make the site cross-browser compatible - literally all I can think to do is to a) try and create a pure CSS dropdown instead or b) have the button display state be controlled by JS so that it appears incorrectly at 994px too (although the menu items will still be horizontally positioned at this point, at least the user will be able to display them by clicking).

Are there any better solutions? Does anything like conditional comments for Firefox exist?

My jQuery looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
     $(".mtoggle").click(function () {
         $("#mmenu").slideToggle(500);
     });
     if ($(window).width() < 980) {
         $("#mmenu").hide();
     }
 });

 $(window).resize(function () {
     if ($(window).width() > 980) {
         $('#mmenu').show();
     }

     if ($(window).width() < 980) {
         $("#mmenu").hide();
     }
 });
</script>
```

I'm running Firefox 23.0.1 which is relatively new so I wonder if it is simply a bug - is anyone else able to replicate it?

Edit: The HTML for the navigation bar is as follows, the full page can be viewed at www.fpsl.eu:

```
<nav id="access" role="navigation" class="navbar-fixed-top">
            <h1 class="assistive-text section-heading">Main menu</h1>
            <div class="skip-link screen-reader-text"><a href="#content" title="Skip to content">Skip to content</a></div>
            <h1 id="site-title"><a href="http://fpsl.eu/" title="First Phase Soft Landing" rel="home"><img src="http://www.fpsl.eu/img/first-phase-logo.png" alt="First Phase Soft Landing" class="logo" /></a></h1>
        <a class="btn-navbar mtoggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".mmenu">
                    <span class="navmenu">&#9776;</span>
                </a>
        <div id="mmenu">
            <div class="menu-first-phase-menu-container"><ul id="menu-first-phase-menu" class="mmenu"><li id="menu-item-83" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-4 current_page_item menu-item-83"><a href="http://fpsl.eu/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-84" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-84"><a href="http://fpsl.eu/about/">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-122" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-122 dropdown"><a href="#">Our Services ▾</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-88"><a href="http://fpsl.eu/market-research/">Market Research</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-87" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-87"><a href="http://fpsl.eu/operational-set-up/">Operational Set Up</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-86" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-86"><a href="http://fpsl.eu/fast-track-services/">Fast Track Services</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-91" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-91"><a href="http://fpsl.eu/testimonials/">Testimonials</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-157" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-157"><a href="http://fpsl.eu/blog/">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-106" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-106"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div>     </div>
        </nav>
```

Edit 2: I have a JSFiddle here using only the header code which works correctly - http://jsfiddle.net/Kg6h4/embedded/result/ . However, when the main content is inserted in the HTML, the problem is still there, see http://jsfiddle.net/juk5w/18/embedded/result/ .

Comment: Could you please reproduce the bug with jsfiddle?

Comment: Also please provide html

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle which is the header code only, which works correctly - http://jsfiddle.net/Kg6h4/2/embedded/result . When the main content is inserted below the header, the jQuery triggers too early, as in this JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/juk5w/18/embedded/result/ . No idea what to do now...